# Tensorflow save and reconstructed model

Tags: python, keras

I'm training my model and saving in h5, it runs just right and gives the final result, but when I rebuild to validate through the test base, my accuracy is at zero, where can I be wronging?

```
   reconstructed_model = keras.models.load_model("Leaf_my_h5_model.h5")
   reconstructed_model.fit(testX, testY)
   predictions = model.predict(testX)
   predictions[0]
   print(predictions)
```

I have this result

7/7 [==============================] - 196s 24s/step - loss: 1.1402 - accuracy: 0.8869
Test loss: 5.902774810791016
Test accuracy: 0.0

Comment: You don't need to fit again. After loading the model, you can directly use `predict`. Or you can use `model.evaluate`

Comment: Call `reconstructed_model.predict()`, not `model.predict()`